# How to fit content correctly in react-native

Tags: react-native

Today i have problem with fitting content in the container in react-native. I used [this](https://github.com/sramezani/radio-buttons-react-native) lib. It is about react-native radio buttons but the content inside that doesn't fit well. Here is the screenshot

[image]

When the text is too large it is going outside. so i decide to open code of that button and saw container of the text tag.

```
centerProductBox: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 6,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal:4,

},
```

Should i changed something or any suggestions what i should changed to fix that?

Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Maybe lower the font-size and add text-align:'center'

Comment: @SrishruthikAlle Is it possible to create large box height?

Comment: Are you creating the radio buttons? or using a library?

Comment: only using library that i sahre above

Comment: Oh alright so I just looked at the docs for the react-native-radio. So try using the 
```renderContainer={RadioButtons.getViewContainerRenderer({
   height: //something here
  })}
``` 
inside the RadioButton tag

Comment: Is it from [this lib](https://github.com/sramezani/radio-buttons-react-native) because i cant use that

Comment: ohh sorry then I was looking at the wrong lib. So I just clicked on the link and saw a `style` prop. So try using the style prop. So, `style={{height://something}}`

Comment: And I also saw a `boxStyle`. So, try messing around with that. So, `boxStyle:{{height:/// something height}}`

Comment: ye i have tried that and nothing happened

Comment: it works . I am so stupid i pasted boxStyle tag at the end and its height is 55. When i remove that it automatically fit the content ! Thank you mate you can comment to upvote you ! @SrishruthikAlle

Comment: Haha okay sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `boxStyle` style prop from the https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-radio-buttons library.